# How to remove columns or rows with missing data in SPARK dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using the following code to remove columns and rows with no or missing values in Spark. However, when I run code to do simple statistics, I receive no numeric value, but "M".
"weathers_df" is my dataframe.

```
weathers_df.na.drop().show()
```

Below is output I receive even after dropping rows with missing values. How can I efficiently remove rows with no/missing value? I used a min and max aggregate function to produce the output below.

```
+--------+----------+---------+
|    Date|DBFhighest|DBFlowest|
+--------+----------+---------+
|20160911|         M|      -20|
|20160320|         M|      -10|
```

The data looks like this:

```
|WBAN|    Date|Time|StationType| SkyCondition|SkyConditionFlag|Visibility|VisibilityFlag|WeatherType|WeatherTypeFlag|DryBulbFarenheit|DryBulbFarenheitFlag|DryBulbCelsius|DryBulbCelsiusFlag|WetBulbFarenheit|WetBulbFarenheitFlag|WetBulbCelsius|WetBulbCelsiusFlag|DewPointFarenheit|DewPointFarenheitFlag|DewPointCelsius|DewPointCelsiusFlag|RelativeHumidity|RelativeHumidityFlag|WindSpeed|WindSpeedFlag|WindDirection|WindDirectionFlag|ValueForWindCharacter|ValueForWindCharacterFlag|StationPressure|StationPressureFlag|PressureTendency|PressureTendencyFlag|PressureChange|PressureChangeFlag|SeaLevelPressure|SeaLevelPressureFlag|RecordType|RecordTypeFlag|HourlyPrecip|HourlyPrecipFlag|Altimeter|AltimeterFlag|
+----+--------+----+-----------+-------------+----------------+----------+--------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+--------------+------------+----------------+---------+-------------+
| 102|20171001|  56|          0|       OVC015|                |     10.00|              |        -RA|               |      42|                    |           5.6|                  |              41|                    |           5.0|          |               40|                     |            4.4|                   |              93|                    |        0|             |          000|                 |                     |                         |          30.01|              |                |                    |              |                  |           30.20|                    |        AA|              |           T|                |    30.19|             |
| 102|20171001| 141|          0|       OVC013|                |     10.00|              |           |               |      43|                    |           6.0|                  |              41|                    |           5.1|          |               39|                     |            4.0|                   |              86|                    |        3|             |          030|                 |                     |                         |          30.02|              |                |                    |              |                  |               M|                    |        AA|              |           T|                |    30.20|             |
```

```
|-- WBAN: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Time: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- StationType: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- SkyCondition: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SkyConditionFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Visibility: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VisibilityFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WeatherType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WeatherTypeFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DryBulbFarenheit: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DryBulbFarenheitFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DryBulbCelsius: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DryBulbCelsiusFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WetBulbFarenheit: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WetBulbFarenheitFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WetBulbCelsius: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WetBulbCelsiusFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DewPointFarenheit: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DewPointFarenheitFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DewPointCelsius: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DewPointCelsiusFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RelativeHumidity: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RelativeHumidityFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WindSpeed: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WindSpeedFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WindDirection: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WindDirectionFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ValueForWindCharacter: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ValueForWindCharacterFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- StationPressure: string (nullable = true)
 |-- StationPressureFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PressureTendency: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PressureTendencyFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PressureChange: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PressureChangeFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SeaLevelPressure: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SeaLevelPressureFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RecordType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RecordTypeFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- HourlyPrecip: string (nullable = true)
 |-- HourlyPrecipFlag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Altimeter: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AltimeterFlag: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you share the schema of the ` weathers_df` using `weathers_df.printSchema` I suspect the data contains non-numeric values and hence the discrepancy in the stats.

Comment: Please see uploaded schema @snithish

Comment: you have posted a sample of the dataframe and not the schema, use `weathers_df.printSchema` for getting the schema.

Comment: Schema attached @snithish

Comment: Maybe `M` refers to missing values and removing them will return the right metric